# How to restore state after calling another activity?

Tags: android, webview, state, restore

My android app is simple : a single activity contains a webview which shows user my website,in it I have a link which when user clicks on it ,the default sms program will be called.

That all works well,but when I return from the sms ,It restarts the program(call the onCreate() method ) instead of returning to the origin state , how can I get back to the state before I turn to the sms program ?

Thanks :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Saving Activity state in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/how-do-i-save-an-android-applications-state) is very similar.